# Python debugging with PyCharm like style

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I'm using Emacs for my Python code. However from time to time I leave my Emacs and try for a few days other editors, just to see if I'm not missing something really cool out there.

With no particular reason,  I started debugging with PyCharm. It's so amazing, I have been looking for something like this for years. What I mean is variable inspection as if it was a comment.

Do you know if there is a way/plugin to have something similar in Emacs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PyCharm, so I don't know exactly what that's like.

`M-x pdb` works fairly well, albeit a bit rough around the edges.  It uses Emacs's gud debugger framework.  It can show the current line in the source buffer, set breakpoints, provides a pdb repl, etc.  The gud key map is at `C-x C-a` in the source buffer, and `C-c` in the gud buffer (e.g. `gud-cont` is at `C-x C-a C-r` in the source or `C-c C-r` in the gud buffer; use `C-x C-a C-h` for help).

Comment: Thanks, @jpkotta for your answer. Yeah, I know gud debugger for Emacs. I just wanted to know if there is something as cool as this visual debugging in PyCharm. Anyway, I will stick to Emacs, but this feature would be awesome.